# How to get average position of my site with google search console api ?

Tags: php, google-api

My website is connected to google search console API.
I would like to make a query that return the average position on my site in google.
Is it possible? i would like to get the average including ALL the keywords?
does any one know any query for this?
The server side is written with php.
I can make a query that return me my website position but only by specific keyword that i need to choose.
 for example:

```
$query = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
    $query->setSearchType('web');
    $query->setDimensions(array('query', 'country', 'device'));
    $query->setStartDate($StartDate);
    $query->setEndDate($EndDate);

    $filterDevice = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilter();
    $filterDevice->setDimension('device');
    $filterDevice->setOperator('equals');
    $filterDevice->setExpression('DESKTOP');

    $filterCountry = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilter();
    $filterCountry->setDimension('country');
    $filterCountry->setOperator('equals');
    $filterCountry->setExpression('fr');

    *******THIS IS FOR A SPECIFIC KEY WORD! ********

    $filterQuery = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilter();
    $filterQuery->setDimension('query');
    $filterQuery->setOperator('equals');
    $filterQuery->setExpression($keyWord);

    ************************************************

    $filtergroup = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilterGroup();
    $filtergroup->setGroupType('and');
    //$filtergroup->setFilters(array($filterDevice,$filterCountry,$filterQuery));
    $filtergroup->setFilters(array($filterDevice,$filterCountry));
    $query->setDimensionFilterGroups(array($filtergroup));

    $response = $webmaster->searchanalytics->query($clientSite,$query);
```

If i do not send any keyword (query) the respond is a lot of keywords and the position of each one, as shown

```
{
"0": {
    "clicks": 3164,
    "ctr": 0.373686075351,
    "impressions": 8467,
    "keys": {
        "0": "KEYWORD_EXAMPLE",
        "1": "fr",
        "2": "DESKTOP"
    },
    "position": 1.00035431676
},
"1": {
    "clicks": 267,
    "ctr": 0.765042979943,
    "impressions": 349,
    "keys": {
        "0": "KEYWORD_EXAMPLE",
        "1": "fr",
        "2": "DESKTOP"
    },
    "position": 1.03438395415
},
"2": {
    "clicks": 204,
    "ctr": 0.0491684743312,
    "impressions": 4149,
    "keys": {
        "0": "KEYWORD_EXAMPLE",
        "1": "fr",
        "2": "DESKTOP"
    },
    "position": 6.57869366112
},
"3": {
    "clicks": 135,
    "ctr": 0.308924485126,
    "impressions": 437,
    "keys": {
        "0": "KEYWORD_EXAMPLE",
        "1": "fr",
        "2": "DESKTOP"
    },
    "position": 1
},
```

TNX!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out...some of the `$filters` did it. if you will send a query without filter it it will work.
for example:

```
$query = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
    $query->setSearchType('web');
    $query->setStartDate($StartDate);
    $query->setEndDate($EndDate);

    $filtergroup = new Google_Service_Webmasters_ApiDimensionFilterGroup();
    $filtergroup->setGroupType('and');
    //***REDUCE THIS LINE! -> $filtergroup->setFilters(array($filterDevice));***//
    $query->setDimensionFilterGroups(array($filtergroup));

    $response = $webmaster->searchanalytics->query($clientSite,$query);
```

The result is:

```
"0": {
    "clicks": 14635,
    "ctr": 0.0629018670701,
    "impressions": 232664,
    "keys": null,
    "position": 15.502961352
}
```

I know this is my correct position because you can see it on your dashboard in google site. (search console GUI).